# Swift: type erased Regex builder

Tags: swift, swift-regexbuilder

I have the following function that uses `Swift 5.7`'s `Regex` builder:

```
static func numberStartingWith6(strictLength: Bool) -> some RegexComponent  {
        let myRegex = Regex {
            
            Optionally {
                "6"
                
                if strictLength {
                    Repeat(CharacterClass.digit, count: 9)
                }
                else {
                    Repeat(0...8) {
                        CharacterClass.digit
                    }
                }
            
            }
        }
```

but i get the following syntax error at the `Optionally` type:

`Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'RegexComponent'`

I tried to figure out the underlying type of the `myRegex` variable in the function above and it was:
`Regex<Regex<Optionally<Substring>. RegexOutput>. RegexOutput>`

How to declare the correct return type in the function's signature so that I don't care about the regex builder's underlying type (i.e. type erasure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RegexComponentBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/regexbuilder/regexcomponentbuilder) doesn't support `if` statements. There is no `buildEither` or `buildIf` methods.

The error is rather confusing. Since you used an `if` statement in the closure, the compiler no longer thinks this is a `@RegexComponentBuilder` closure, and tries to match the other initialiser overloads. It found [this overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/regexbuilder/optionally/init(_:_:)-2zdez) that takes a `RegexComponent`, and says the closure (of type `() -> ()`) can't be converted to that.

`if` statements are not supported possibly because if the branches capture different things, the `Output` type of the resulting regex is going to be very complicated.

For example, if you have

```
if x {
    // here you capture an Int, a Substring, and a Double
} else if y {
    // here you capture an Double, a Float, and a Date
} else {
    // here you capture a Decimal, a Boolean and a Substring
```

Then the `Output` type of the regex would be

```
(Substring, Int?, Substring?, Double?, Double?, Float?, Date?, Decimal?, Boolean?, Substring?)

or

(Substring, (Int, Substring, Double)?, (Double, Float, Date)?, (Decimal, Boolean, Substring)?)
```

The amount of `buildEither` and `buildIf` overloads needed for this is rather unmanageable.

You can write a `buildEither` yourself if you only capture the same types in each branch:

```
// this won't work if you capture different types in each branch of an if
extension RegexComponentBuilder {
    static func buildEither<T>(first component: Regex<T>) -> Regex<T> {
        buildPartialBlock(first: component)
    }
    
    public static func buildEither<T>(second component: Regex<T>) -> Regex<T> {
        buildPartialBlock(first: component)
    }
}
```

That said, your code does not need an if statement. Just do:

```
Repeat(strictLength ? 9...9 : 0...8) {
    CharacterClass.digit
}
```

Or if the regex component in each branch is a different type, you can just declare a `let`:

```
Regex {
    
    Optionally {
        "6"
        let temp: any RegexComponent<Substring /* or any other output you want*/> = {
            if strictLength {
                return ChoiceOf {
                    "a"
                    CharacterClass.digit
                }
            } else {
                return Optionally {
                    "b"
                }
            }
        }()
        
        // then use temp somewhere...
        temp
        
    }
}
```